# I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, django

The error that I get after the command "python manage.py runserver":

```
from LoginAPI.LoginApp.views import register_view, login_view, logout_view
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LoginAPI.LoginApp'
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from LoginAPI.LoginApp.views import register_view, login_view, logout_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^register/', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
]
```

Django version: 2.1.1
I am not very experienced in python yet and would love to here your feedback, I have searched for solutions but couldn't seem to find any. Maybe that I missed something small but can't seem to find the problem.

EDIT:
The file hierarchy is as displayed:
You have the folder: "LoginAPI"
which contains the two folders: "LoginAPI" and "LoginApp"
The folder "LoginAPI" contains the file "urls.py"
The folder "LoginApp" contains a file "views.py"

Comment: python is not able to find LoginAPI.LoginApp 
can you share where is loginApi module is

Comment: it would be useful if you posted the file hierarchy - where is this file? where is the LoginApi module located relative to this file?

Comment: I have updated the file hierarchy in the post, I hope it is enough?

Comment: Put a file named `__init__.py` (it doesn't matter that is empty) inside your folder `loginAPI`.

Comment: `loginApi.loginApp` is not the same as `LoginApi.LoginApp`. Which is it?

Comment: It is LoginApp sorry for the inconvenience. I have placed a __init__.py inside the folder LoginAPI bu it still doesn't work

Comment: I just realize that in django 2 there's no need to add `__init__.py`. We can asume that `LoginAPI/` folder is under the `rootdirectory/` folder?

Comment: And I know that you stated that the django version is 2... can i ask you if you are _sure_ of it?

Comment: Yeah I just checked and it is Django version 2.1.1 and the API is the root directory folder contains the LoginAPI which contains the other two directories.

Answer (score 0):

If your **project root directory** is `LoginAPI` then you don't add it to call the modules.

Assuming then from what you specify as folder structure

```
# project root directory
LoginAPI/
    # app directories
    LoginAPI/
        urls.py
    LoginApp/
        views.py
```

So you should call

```
from LoginApp.views import register_view, login_view, logout_view
```